# VSC C#: Referencing Microsoft DLLs

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to port a C# .NET Core project from Visual Studio 2019 to Visual Studio Code, although I have no experience with using VSC for C#. I managed to set up NuGet references using `dotnet add package`, however I cannot wrap my head around importing DLLs that are already present in Windows, such as `System.Windows.Forms`.

This has been done via a GUI menu in VS19, however that cannot be the case with Powershell commands. Futhermore, I used a `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` package to get it working on .NET Core, rather than .NET Framework. I attempted using `dotnet add package System.Windows.Forms` along `dotnet add package Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility`, however, after `dotnet run`, I get the following errors in the Terminal:

> warning NU1701: Package 'System.Windows.Forms 4.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

> Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Reference assemblies should
> not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (0x80131058)
> File name: 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.

How can I get this working in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: if deploy machine does not have same version of net as build machine you need to publish and install using setup.exe.

Comment: @jdweng Unfortunately, I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: Do you know what publish means in VS?  The Compile menu has a PUBLISH option which produces a setup.exe like commercial purchased software.  You need to install the setup.exe folder like commercial software.